# Ingress configuration to access Kibana from the internet

Tags: kibana, kubernetes-ingress

I've been following this guide here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud-on-k8s/master/k8s-deploy-kibana.html, and I have also configured the following ingress:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: kibana-ui
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: "false"
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /kibana
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: quickstart-kb-http
            port:
              number: 5601
```

The port forwarding worked just fine
But with this ingress, I get a 502 page.
How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the suggestion in this thread [here](https://github.com/elastic/helm-charts/issues/779).
So I added the following annotation:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
```

the full ingress config:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: kibana-ui
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  tls:
  - hosts:
      - xx.xx.xx.xx.nip.io
    secretName: quickstart-kb-http-ca-public
  rules:
  - host: xx.xx.xx.xx.nip.io
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: quickstart-kb-http
            port:
              number: 5601
```

Also i used the nip.io workaround. Coz apparently you need to use a name as opposed to ip in the host section above.

Comment: I tried your solution but nginx redirects from goofy.com/kibana to goofy.com/login?next=%2Fkibana%2F and I don't know why. Any idea? Thanks